# Be able to show the next value in a Linked List by clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms

This is probably a simple task however I am unable to solve.

So currently I have set up a form which contains a textbox and a button and I want to be able to click the button and the first value within the LinkedList will show up in the textbox. If I click the button again then the next value will show up etc.

I currently go it so that the first value will show up but then I am unable to proceed to the next value.

This is the code I have currently:

```
public class Node
{
    public string data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(string newData)
    {
        data = newData;
        next = null;
    }

    public void AddEnd(string data)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = new Node(data);
        }
        else
        {
            next.AddEnd(data);
        }
    }
}

public class myList
{
    public void AddEnd(string data)
    {
        if (headnode == null)
        {
            headnode = new Node(data);
        }
        else
        {
            headnode.AddEnd(data);
        }
    }

    public string getFirst() // this gets the first value within the list and returns it
    {
        if (headnode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("List is empty");
        }

        Node node = headnode;
        while (node.next != null)
        {
         node = node.next;   
        }
        return node.data;
    }
```

I also tried using this:

```
public class NavigationList<T> : List<T>
{
    private int _currentIndex = -1;
    public int CurrentIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentIndex == Count)
                _currentIndex = 0;
            else if (_currentIndex > Count - 1)
                _currentIndex = Count - 1;
            else if (_currentIndex < 0)
                 _currentIndex = 0;

            return _currentIndex;
        }
            set { _currentIndex = value; }
    }

    public T MoveNext
    {
        get { _currentIndex++; return this[CurrentIndex]; }
    }
        public T Current
    {
        get { return this[CurrentIndex]; }
    }
}
```

However, I am not really familiar with something like this so I wasn't sure on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a sequence of items, and the only thing that you want, is to get the first item, and once you've got an item, every time your ask for it, you want the next item, until there are no more items left.

In `.NET` this is called an `IEnumerable`, or if you know what kind of items are in your sequence, for instance items of `MyClass`, it is called an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. In your case you need an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Luckily `.NET` is loaded with classes that implement `IEnumerable`. Two of the most used ones are array and list. You seldom have to create an enumerable class yourself, re-use the existing ones and enumerate over it.

```
List<string> myData = ... // fill this list somehow.

IEnumerator<string> myEnumerator = null // we are not enumerating yet.

string GetNextItemToDisplay()
{    // returns null if there are no more items to display

     // if we haven't started yet, get the enumerator:
     if (this.myEnumerator == null) this.myEnumerator = this.myData.GetEnumerator();

     // get the next element (or if we haven't fetched anything yet: get the first element
     // for this we use MoveNext. This returns false if there is no next element
     while (this.myEnumerator.MoveNext())
     {
          // There is a next string. It is in Current:
          string nextString = enumerator.Current();
          return nextString;
     }

     // if here: no strings left. return null:
     return null;
}
```

This looks like a lot of code, but if you remove the comments it is in fact just a few lines of code:

```
string GetNextItemToDisplay()
{
     if (this.myEnumerator == null) this.myEnumerator = this.myData.GetEnumerator();
     while (this.myEnumerator.MoveNext())
          return enumerator.Current();
     return null;
}
```

Your ButtonClick event handler:

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
     string nextItemToDisplay = this.GetNextItemToDisplay();
     if (nextItemToDisplay != null)
        this.Display(nextItemToDisplay);
     else
        this.DisplayNoMoreItems():
}
```

If you want to start over again with the first element, for instance after changing the List

```
void RestartEnumeration()
{
    this.myEnumerator = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I am unable to use this as I am currently in school so once I get home I'll check back with you to see if it works.